# Center Button Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image: Screen Shot]

The screenshot is taken from an 5s IPhone.

[image: Screen Shot]

The screenshot is taken from an 6s IPhone.

[image: Screen Shot]

Image Set From **Main Storyborad** :

[image: Screen Shot]

In first picture the center button is all good but i am really confused center button alignment from top or bottom is perfectly set in 6s but in 5s which not set properly.

How to set from top as well as bottom in all devices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the **bottom** image inset opposite to the **top** inset

[image]